# Issue with datetime remaining at epoch

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, time-series

I've got a dataframe with one column filled with milliseconds that I've been able to convert somewhat into datetime format. The issue is that for two years worth of data, from 2017-2018, the time output remains at 1-1-1970. The output datetime looks like this:

> 27      1970-01-01 00:25:04.232399999
>
> 28      1970-01-01 00:25:04.232699999
>
> 29      1970-01-01 00:25:04.232999999

```
                 ...
```

> 85264   1970-01-01 00:25:29.962799999
>
> 85265   1970-01-01 00:25:29.963099999
>
> 85266   1970-01-01 00:25:29.963399999

It seems to me that the milliseconds, which begin at 1504224299999 and end at 1529971499999, are getting added to the 10th hour of epoch and are not representing the true range that it should.

This is my code so far...

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',db='binance',passwd='abcde')
cur = con.cursor()
ms = pd.read_sql('SELECT close_time FROM btcusdt', con=con)

ms['close_time'].apply( lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000) )
date = pd.to_datetime(ms['close_time'])
print(date)
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong, so if anybody can tell me what I'm doing stupidly it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try: `ms['close_time'].apply( lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000) )` whats the dtype for `ms['close_time']` ??

Comment: @Mankind_008, it still says float64, dtype: object & puts out the same error

Comment: @Mankind_008, so I added that before using your initial code suggestion and now I've got the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Timestamp' and 'int'

Comment: post some dummy data from: `ms['close_time']`

Comment: @Mankind_008, this is as from the dataframe, added commas for readability: 
0    1.504224e+12,
1    1.504225e+12,
2    1.504225e+12,
3    1.504225e+12,
4    1.504225e+12,
5    1.504226e+12,
6    1.504226e+12,
7    1.504226e+12

Comment: @Mankind_008, hey I ended up switching the order of the codes that you had given me (to the order that you had posted them) and it returns the datetime, but only as the first day of January of epoch, despite being a 2 year dataset.... seems like the right direction though.

Comment: You will have to dig deeper. or edit this post with the new issue along with data so others can help better.

Comment: @Mankind_008, will do. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: i have added a solution summarizing my comments. please do add your previous issue as well to make sense for others requiring help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to apply a function that doesn't support your argument directly, you can `apply` it element wise using *dummy function* `lambda`.

Also, you need to assign back to your original panda series to overwrite it, use:

```
ms['close_time'] = ms['close_time'].apply( lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000) )
```

If you want to use `pandas.to_datetime` directly. use:

```
pd.to_datetime(ms['close_time'], unit = 'ms')
```

*PS.* There might be difference in `datetime` obtained from these two methods